# Insert Query in registration form

Tags: c#, sql, insert, registration

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
protected void registerBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
      {
       outputlabel.Text = "Succesfully Registered";
       myConnection.Open();
       string query = "Insert into Users (FirstName,LastName,Gender,DateOfBirth,
         Email_Id,Password) Values (@fn,@ln,@gen,@dob,@em,@pas)";
       SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", fname.Text);
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", lname.Text);
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", gender_dd.SelectedItem.Text);
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", date.Text);
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", email.Text);
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password.Text);
       insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       myConnection.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Help me in this code..how can i edit this.If the same information is enter.Than code as show the message as already register.So no duplication in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a SQL statement that checks if the user currently exists in the database **before** executing the `INSERT into USERS` statement.

So the code below will check if the user already exists based on the *email address* and *password* values they have supplied.

```
string userInvalid = "The username entered is invalid, please choose another."
string checkDatabase = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email_Id = @em AND Password = @pas";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checkDatabase, myConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", email.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows) {
  outputlabel.Text = userInvalid;
}
else 
{
  // execute your original SQL query 
}
```

Comment: thanks,but now i am getting this error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object..how can i get rid of this?

Comment: userAlreadyExist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;  At this line of code show error(executing an execute scalar cast to int and not verifying for DBNULL),how can i corrrect this?

Comment: @smoggers has given you a correct answer, but you must think how to optimize the code. With this you currently make two calls to your SQL Server. You can either add a unique constrain in your table, when you have duplicate data an exception will be thrown so you can handle it or create a function which will have an output parameter where you can return a "code" to know if the registration succeeded or not. Both proposals make only one call to the SQL Server.

Comment: @ifrah any progress ?

Comment: @smoggers..not yet.:( query was ok but it shows the error of connection .Actually i am new to asp.net that's why i am getting confuse,and didn't understand what's the actual problem.

Comment: @ifrah it's very difficult for us to resolve without seeing the error stacktrace, I realise you're new to this site but going forward you'd get further by adding the stacktrace. as for a connection problem again hard to diagnose without seeing the code you have that attempts to connect to the database

Comment: @smoggers..i have resolve my issue of connection problem..connection already closed in my function.but it shows the error connection state open...i solved it by using exception handling.now the code executed properly.thanks for your help.

Comment: @EmmanouilChountasis yes you right now my problem is solved.Thanks for your comment